# Is there other option to use string resources in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I'm kinda new in the Android world, and I'm learning Android with Jetpack Compose.
As you already know, Compose is trying to replace all the .xml files but in a particular case, I'm using a string.xml file to store all my "static text". But these files are .xml files so... I'm wondering if there is another option for using this string resources in Android without .xml files

This is an example of the xml file that I am using

```
<resources>
   <string name="this_is_an_example">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

And I'm using the string resources in mi kotlin files like this

```
stringResource(id = R.string.this_is_an_example)
```

Comment: String resources by definition are XML files. You are welcome to store strings in your app in some other fashion, though. See [lyricist](https://github.com/adrielcafe/lyricist) for a Compose-specific approach.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much, I'll read the documentation and try to implement that on my project.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if there is an official way but one way you could do it is a file with strings in it.
e.g.
val thisIsAnExample = "hello world"

then use it where ever you wanted.
an enum class for strings would work as well